# Self generating list where each element appends some elements to the end

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a way to do something like this.
Say we start with 1. For every number odd number we add it +5 to the end of the list. For every even number we add it +3 and it +7 to the end of the list. The list would look like this

[1, 6, 9, 13, 14, 18, 17, 21, 21, 25,...]

How would I go about doing something like this in Haskell?

I'm aware that you can make a list where each element depends on the previous ones, but how do you do it when more than one element depends on the same one, and you don't know which group depends on which unless you start from the beginning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's quite similar to how you would do it if only a single element was being generated at a time. In that case you would pass down a single value to keep track of the "seed" for the next elements. In this situation you can just pass down a list instead:

```
xs = process [1]

-- notice no [] case as we don't expect it to be needed
process (n:ns) = n:process (ns ++ extras)
  where
   extras
     | n `mod` 2 == 0 = [n+3, n+7]
     | otherwise = [n+5]
```

The general idea is that the argument to `process` contains all the numbers that we know should be in the output list, but for which we haven't yet added the "consequent" numbers. To make progress, we inspect the first of those, "output" it by putting it at the head of the result, and calculate the consequent numbers and put those into the list that's waiting to be processed. By putting them at the end we make sure that everything gets its turn, so to speak.

Note that putting them at the end using naive list concatenation means that this algorithm will technically take linear time in how far it's got through the list to produce the next number. This can be handled by using a more efficient data structure such as [Data.Sequence](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Sequence.html).

Comment: This is bending my brain... Damn you Haskell and your beautiful headachyness. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: I added some explanation in case that helps you understand it.

Comment: Would Data.Sequence really help here? It seems to me that it would make the algorithm strict, so that you couldn't get any results out before computing the entire list (since any step could add a new element to the front). That's more efficient for finite lists, but since the original question asked for an infinite list, it will be "a bit" slower using Data.Sequence.

Comment: I meant use `Data.Sequence` for the argument to `process`, not the result list. The argument list that keeps track of what to do next is always finite. You could also keep it simpler (and lazy) with pair of lists, one reversed and one not [add to the head of the second and remove from the head of the first, and reverse the second into the first whenever the first empties.]

Answer (score 13):

The following solution uses a self-referencing lazy list, and so doesn't have the linear time problem of the solution by @GaneshSittampalam:

```
xs = 1 : concatMap extras xs where
  extras x
    | odd x     = [x+5]
    | otherwise = [x+3,x+7]
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. These self-recursive data structures are often hard for me to untangle, and this is a really cool example to practice on.

Comment: This still takes linear space to traverse though, right? Every time an even item is encountered, the size of "work not yet done" increases by one, and it never decreases. I think that's fundamental to his problem, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something even cleverer in your approach. It seems to behave that way in some simple testing, as well.

Comment: Yes, linear space is inevitable unless you figure out some clever optimisation based on the structure of the arithmetic - there's always going to be a queue of things waiting to do. As well as using linear space, mine has a linear _time_ slowdown which this doesn't, so I think this solution is strictly better than mine. You can see this quite easily by looking for xs!!100000 in ghci - mine takes a very long time while this one returns almost instantly - linear time to produce a single element means quadratic time to produce the nth element.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam So, I couldn't resist trying to find one, quite specific to this case though: `let f 2 = 1; f 3 = 6; f x | even x = f h + 8 | otherwise = f h + 12 where h = div x 2 in map f [2..]`

Comment: @amalloy Posted a comment above with a hack that uses less space, depends on specific arithmetic though.

Answer (score 0):

My Haskell sucks so here's an outline with fake code.

You can do it with a filter.

Note that for any odd number: 2x+1
You'll add 2x+6 to your list

For ever even number: 2x
You'll add 2x+3 and 2x+7

so:

```
filter (f) naturalNumbers

where f(x) :  
  true if (x-7) % 2 == 0
  true if (x-6) % 2 == 0
  true if (x-3) % 2 == 0
  false otherwise
```

Comment: Unfortunately this wouldn't work since 21 will only appear once in your list and it appears twice in mine. Also, I'm not sure if you can guarantee that the list will be ordered. But most of all (I definitely should have explained better), the idea is that you can't use simple math to turn the list into a recursion of itself. The thing I actually want to do isn't as simple as my example.

Comment: Oops I didn't notice it appeared twice, I thought you just wanted a set.